# jquery tree view plugin with context menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, treeview

we are looking for a jquery tree view plugin **with context menu** for our application.We found some of good plugin jsTree. But we are interesting the plugin called fancyTree(dynatree).

http://wwwendt.de/tech/fancytree/demo/

If any one has experience with this? how about community and we have a consideration of performance too.

thanks

Comment: Please read this : http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic - Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.